# List of non-native terrestrial molluscs in California?

Tags: zoology

I'm looking for a list of non-native terrestrial molluscs in California. Ideally, I also need the date each taxon was introduced into California. Can anyone help?

Comment: This might be a start: [Wikipedia: List of invasive species in North America: Mollusks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_invasive_species_in_North_America#Mollusks).